# WPF MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit Snackbar different style for each message

Tags: wpf, styles, snackbar, material-design-in-xaml

How to change the style (eg background/foreground colors) for different messages?
I want to show Sucess, Info and Error messages with different styles.

I tried using bindings with a converter like this:

**XAML:**

```
<materialDesign:Snackbar
    x:Name="MainSnackbar"
    Grid.Row="0"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    ActionButtonPlacement="Inline"
    Background="{Binding MessageQueueType, Converter={StaticResource StatusToMessageBackgroundColorConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    Foreground="{Binding MessageQueueType, Converter={StaticResource StatusToMessageForegroundColorConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    MessageQueue="{Binding MessageQueue}" />
```

**Converter C#:**

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        switch ((MessageQueueStatus)value)
        {
            case MessageQueueStatus.Error:
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkRed);
            case MessageQueueStatus.Info:
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DimGray);
            case MessageQueueStatus.Sucess:
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.ForestGreen);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

VM C#:

```
private void ShowSnackMessage(string message, MessageQueueStatus messageQueueType, bool ClearOtherMessages = false)
    {
        if(ClearOtherMessages)
            MessageQueue.Clear();
        MessageQueueType = messageQueueType;
        MessageQueue.Enqueue(message);
    }
```

But the if I queue more than 1 type of message at a time, only the last selected 'style' is applied. If I queue first an 'Info' message than a 'Success' message, both will show as 'Sucess style'.

I achieved what I want creating 3 different Snackbars directly in XAML with different styles set and 3 different *MessageQueues* in VM.
But this way I need to create a different object and queue for each style I need.
Is this the only way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We made a trick to have this behaviour without having the need of multiple snack bars.

The idea is to keep the list of enqueued messages in the snackbar in a separate list and when a message is removed from the snack bar (just before putting the next one) we change the background color of the snackbar with a trigger on a property containing the info to choose the color.

Our snackbar in xaml

```xml
 <materialDesign:Snackbar Name="MainSnackbar" ActionButtonStyle="{StaticResource SnackActionButton}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" MessageQueue="{Binding MessageQueue}" Message="{Binding Message, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <utilities:TreeHelpers.Modifiers>
        <utilities:ModifierCollection >
            <utilities:Modifier TemplatePartName="ContentBorder" Property="{x:Static Border.CornerRadiusProperty}" Value="20 20 0 0">
            </utilities:Modifier>
        </utilities:ModifierCollection>
    </utilities:TreeHelpers.Modifiers>
    <materialDesign:Snackbar.Style>
        <Style TargetType="materialDesign:Snackbar" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type materialDesign:Snackbar}}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MaterialDesignSnackbarBackground}"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=AppGrid}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding CurrentMessageLevel, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource FwBrushError}"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding CurrentMessageLevel, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource FwBrushWarning}"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding CurrentMessageLevel, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="3">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource FwBrushInfo}"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding CurrentMessageLevel, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="4">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource FwBrushSuccess}"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </materialDesign:Snackbar.Style>
</materialDesign:Snackbar>
```

The part where we enqueue messages

```cs
public class MessageToSnack
{
    public string Content { get; set; } = "";
    public MessageToSnackLevel Level { get; set; } = 0;
    public TimeSpan? Duration { get; set; } = null; // if null it will use the default duration of material design -> 3s
    public bool WithCloseButton { get; set; } = true;
}

public enum MessageToSnackLevel
{
    NoLevel = 0,
    Error = 1,
    Warning = 2,
    Info = 3,
    Success = 4,
}

private void EventSnackMessageReceived(MessageToSnack snakMsg)
{
    _snackedMessages.Add(snakMsg);

    if (snakMsg.WithCloseButton)
    {
        MessageQueue.Enqueue(snakMsg.Content, new PackIcon() { Kind = PackIconKind.Close}, (queue) => CloseCommand(queue), MessageQueue, false, false, snakMsg.Duration);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageQueue.Enqueue(snakMsg.Content, null, null, null, false, false, snakMsg.Duration);
    }
}
```

The part to manage the CurrenMessageLevel property

```cs
List<MessageToSnack> _snackedMessages = new List<MessageToSnack>(); // used when intercepting a snackbar message poping , to find its reference and be able to change the color with a trigger on the CurrentLevel

private SnackbarMessage _message;
public SnackbarMessage Message
{
    get { return _message; }
    set 
    { 
        SetProperty(ref _message, value);

        if (_message != null)
        {
            var localMessage = _snackedMessages.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Content.Equals(_message.Content.ToString()));
            if (localMessage != null)
            {
                CurrentMessageLevel = localMessage.Level;
                _snackedMessages.Remove(localMessage);
            }
            else
            {
                CurrentMessageLevel = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            CurrentMessageLevel = 0;
        }
    }
}

private MessageToSnackLevel _currentMessageLevel;
public MessageToSnackLevel CurrentMessageLevel
{
    get { return _currentMessageLevel; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _currentMessageLevel, value); }
}
```

Comment: where does "utilities" come from?

Comment: Its coming from there https://github.com/Keboo/MaterialDesignInXaml.Examples/tree/b03dfedd1f9c06b9042f0b9dd2006faf1dd3555a/Utilities/Utilities and is used to change some part of templates without retemplating everything just for one property